# UITableView reload the data of a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I have a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass that is dequeued and displayed in the `UITableView` with no problem.

However there is a little label on the section view that counts the rows of this section - and what I want is when I delete/insert a new row in this section to update this `countLabel`.

Tried many things but they all assume I'm NOT using `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and include manipulating the view directly which is a bit hacky.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get pointer to your header view and change text of your little label:

```
YourHeaderView *headerView = [self.table headerViewForSection:affectedSectionIndex];
headerView.countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newCount];
```

This will update your header view, if it is already on screen.

This solution also may look hacky, but for me it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly when you insert/delete items then you can call reloadSections:withRowAnimation: on the table view. This should trigger update of the section header and footer.